# How to change background of Month cell and weekdays cell in Caldroid library in android

Tags: android, fragment, caldroid

Iam using caldroid library for my project. I dont know how to change the month cell background and weekday cell background.

Answer (score 1):

if you have access to the caldroidLib file data then you access its res folder data and make changes to the res->layout folder files where the gridview and the custom gridview exists in the same file. change the color or some more data whatever you need to make changes into the calendar.
After making change again declare it as a library.[image: this is the gridview and the caldroid calendar inside the caldroid layout folder. filename->calendar_view.xml]